# Can we access SystemCertificates folder programmatically?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, certificate

Is it possible to programmatically access SystemCertificates folder in the local app package?

I have the user certificates installed into this folder :
"dir>/AppData\Local\Packages\<Package Name>\AC\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates"

I am not able to find a way to delete the certificates in this location. Also, when I try to do something like this (with the absolute path to the AC folder):

```
StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync()
```

it gives me "not accessible" error

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe you have access to that folder without explicit permission. The certificate should only be able to get there via adding it to your app manifest. I wonder if removing the reference would eventually delete the cert, though it's possibly not. Why do you need to delete the certificate?

Comment: We provide the user of our client to switch from certificate based authentication to username/password authentication. If user does that we do not need to retain the certificates for the user which were previously installed.